# Python - Attempting login class

Tags: python-3.x, class, return

I am attempting to do a simple login class in python that will verify username information from a .txt file, if it is valid it will send that data over to the verify password method. I have gotten the code to work for the most part but once I enter the right information it is not wanting to return from the class. I am not 100% sure why, it keeps going back to my user_find() class instead of back to the main program. Any help on what I might be missing to get the class to return instead of returning to the user_find method. Thank you,

```
class Login:
def user_find(self):
    with open("users.txt") as file:
        file_reader = csv.reader(file)
        count = 3
        while count > 0:
            user = input("Please enter your username: ")
            for row in file_reader:
                if row[0] == user:
                    print("Username Found")
                    user_found = [row[0], row[1]]
                    Login.pass_check(user_found)

            print("Invalid Username")
            count -= 1
            print(f"You have {count} attempts to login left.")                     
        
        file.close()
        return "Unable to login, please contact your administrator."

def pass_check(self):
    count = 3
    while count > 0:
        password = input("Please enter your password: ")
        if self[1] == password:
            print("Login Successful!")
            return
        
        print("Invalid Password")
        count -= 1
        print(f"You have {count} attempts to login left.")

    return
```

[Code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GsRc.png)

[Calling login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rpIB.png)

Comment: What does your main look like?  In other words how are you invoking this?  Also, your indentation is off

Comment: I added a screenshot of my login method.

Answer (score 0):

With the overriding caveat, that a login verification function should not ever be written this way for numerous security reasons, for which I am not competent to answer.  As a learning experience, you code includes several problems with the impelmentation as written to include:

1. If variable user id is found in users.txt, users.txt is never closed
2. The method csv.reader creates a reader that reads the opened file in the forward direction only, thus the multiple attempts at entering a user name will not succeed.,  The reader pointer needs to be reset for each pass.
3. The call to the class instance of check_pass should be made as self.check_pass(user_found), to ensure it employs the current instance of the method.
4. The call to pass_checker written as Login.pass_checker(user_found) will fail, since the method pass_checker is designed to accept only one variable **self**.
5. In the function login, the test for user input of 'y' fails to allow for capital "Y" being entered.  While not technically, wrong fails to accommodate user foibles
6. The multiple uses of similar variable names Login (a Class), login ( a function), login ( a class instantiation), and login a str variable assigned as the return of an input statement can lead to coding errors and code understanding issues.
7. The method check_pass doesn't include the passed variable for the txt file row.
8. within the check_pass method the line self[0] == password will fail for two reasons. (1)self[0] doesn't contain the desired value for the test and (2)Since the password being checked comes from a csv file and could be a numeric rather than a string variable.

This is how I would modify your code as written to make it work.

```
import csv
class Login:
    # Class to handle Login Verification 
    
    def user_find(self):
        """Requests User Id and verifies it exists in users.txt 
            Returns the userid if found, else returns None """
        with open("users.txt") as file:
            file_reader = csv.reader(file)
            count = 2
            while count >= 0:
                file.seek(0)  # Repositions read pointer to start of file
                user = input("Please enter your username: ")
                user_found = None
                for row in file_reader:
                    if row[0].lower() == user.lower():
                        count = -1
                        user_found = row
                        break
 
                if user_found:       #Test for valid userId being detected
                    file.close()  # closes file on exit from while loop
                    if self.pass_check(user_found):
                        return user_found[0]
                    else:
                        return None                        
                else:
                    print("Invalid Username")
                    print(f"You have {count} attempts to login left.")
                    count -= 1 
            file.close()  # closes file on exit from while loop
            return None                                    

  
    def pass_check(self, row):
        """ Checks for valid password entry.  If entry is valid, 
            returns True, else False"""
        count = 3
        while count > 0:
            password = input("Please enter your password: ")
            if str(row[1]).strip() == password.strip():
                return True
        
            print("Invalid Password")
            count -= 1
            print(f"You have {count} attempts to login left.")
        return False
```

with the initiation function as:

```
def start():
    # Function to initiate login operations
    logReq = input("Login to your accouhnt (Y/N) ")
    if logReq.lower() == 'y':  # This ensures that if the user types 
                               # upper or lower case, it is detected
        logProc = Login()
        if logProc.user_find():
            print('Welcome to the System')
        else:
            print('Please contact your administrator to setup your account')
    else:
        print ('Goodbye')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that does explain a lot of my issues. I first tried to have my pass_check take a parameter, but couldn't seem to get it to work correctly. But now I see what I did wrong.